# create a formula for excel to find a value using row and col

Tags: excel

I have 1st table with the information:

[image: Table with information]

and this is my second table (pivot kind of...)
[image]

**i want to have the information from the 1st table into the 2nd table (2nd image).
Ie. formula return me the values as checking the row as eg. Arabic and col heading as AEG and return the corresponding ar_AR ...**

Comment: yes... let say.. AEG as AEMDX

Comment: Then... say... use an [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) with two [MATCH functions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca).

Comment: I tried ..but dont know...what was wrong with that..!!! this has erased my brain to work.. :(

Comment: tried this: =INDEX(ttx[CMSLocale],MATCH(1,(ttx[CMS_Id]=F2)*(ttx[GMSLocale]=E3),0)) ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP($A3,Sheet2!$A$2:$B$6,2,FALSE)=Sheet3!B$2,VLOOKUP(Sheet3!$A3,Sheet2!$A$2:$C$6,3,FALSE),"Value Not Found")
```

Assuming your data is on `Sheet2` and you want the result on `Sheet3`. Copy paste the formula in cell `B3` and drag it across all the rows and columns.

[image]

***Note:** I've added column `AEG` in `E` just to show the sample result.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1) to test within an [IF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) statement whether the column is the appropriate one and then if it is another VLOOKUP to return the appropriate value, otherwise nothing:

```
 =IF(VLOOKUP($G2,$A:$B,2,0)=H$1,VLOOKUP($G2,$A:$C,3,0),"")
```

Use whatever the appropriate cell references are for your layout.

Comment: whats the G2 and h1 over here?